# x86 mov / add Instructions & Memory Addressing

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, att

I'm learning x86 assembly in class and I'm very lost as to how you differentiate between what a register operand and what a memory reference does. I had several confusions I was hoping to clear up.

The following code is what my textbook says is the long way to do push and pop respectively:

```
subl $4, %esp
movl %ebp, (%esp)

movl (%esp), %eax
addl $4, %esp
```

So in the subl instruction, can we always expect %esp to hold an address value?

Also what is the difference between the two movl functions? Can the first one be written as

```
movl (%ebp), %esp
```

? And for the second movl, does that move the address of %esp or does it move the value pointed to by %esp?

As a follow-up then, why can't we have the source and destination be memory references like so?

```
movw (%eax), 4(%esp)
```

And lastly, for the following code:

```
movb (%esp, %edx, 4), %dh
```

if the source is more than 1 byte (the size of %dh), then what happens? Does it just truncate the value?

Sorry, this was a ton of questions but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following code is what my textbook says is the long way to do push
>   and pop respectively:
>
> ```
> subl $4, %esp
> movl %ebp, (%esp)
>
> movl (%esp), %eax
> addl $4, %esp
> ```
>
> So in the subl instruction, can we always expect %esp to hold an
>   address value?

Yes. The `ESP` register holds the memory address of the last value pushed into the stack.

> Also what is the difference between the two movl functions? Can the
>   first one be written as
>
> ```
> movl (%ebp), %esp
> ```
>
> ? And for the second movl, does that move the address of %esp or does 
>   it move the value pointed to by %esp?

The `MOV` instruction, in `AT&T` syntax, expects two operands: source and destination. `MOV` copies data (in this case, 32 bits, as denoted by the `L` suffix) from the first operand written at the left, to the second operand, written at the right. If one of them is enclosed in parenthesis, that means that the operand is a memory operand, and the value in parenthesis is its memory address, rather than the actual value)

So, `movl %ebp,(%esp)` means: copy the value of register `EBP` into memory, at the address pointed by the value of register `ESP`.

What you meant with `movl (%ebp),%esp` is: copy 32 bits of data starting at the memory address pointed by the value of `EBP`, into the `ESP` register.

So you are changing the direction of the movement.

> As a follow-up then, why can't we have the source and destination be
>   memory references like so?
>
> ```
> movw (%eax), 4(%esp)
> ```

Short answer: because the encoding used by Intel doesn't allow that. Long answer: the way Intel designed the ISA, available resources to calculate two effective addresses in the good old 8086, etc

> And lastly, for the following code:
>
> ```
> movb (%esp, %edx, 4), %dh
> ```
>
> if the source is more than 1 byte (the size of %dh), then what
>   happens? Does it just truncate the value?

The source is the same size as the destination. This is imposed both by the `B` suffix and the fact that the destination is an 8-bit register. The value iin parenthesis is then the address of a single memory byte. By the way, this address is `ESP+EDX*4`

Comment: Check your explanation of `movl (%ebp),%esp`, I don't think that's right

Comment: Thank you! That was very in-depth and helpful. I was actually about to ask the same about your comment on that. Wouldn't it copy the value pointed to by %ebp onto %esp?

Comment: Ah! Right! I made myself a mess with EBP and ESP. Fixed!

Comment: @harold If you guys have time, would you mind answering one more quick question?

If I have an int* x stored at ebp and I have movl 8(%ebp), %edi 
Would the movl mean I store the int that x points to at %edi or just x to %edi?

Comment: @ChangLiu if you have stored it in `(%ebp)` then accessing `8(%ebp)` has essentially nothing to do with it, but even if that's where `x` is actually stored then just reading `x` doesn't dereference `x`, you just get `x` itself.

Comment: @harold Oh sorry, yeah I meant if int* x was stored at 8(%ebp). Does 8(%ebp) then get the address of the memory block that holds the pointer or does it get what the pointer points to?

Answer (score 1):

> So in the subl instruction, can we always expect %esp to hold an address value?

By definition yes, because the next instruction uses it as an address. Whatever junk was in there is now an address. If it's some crap like 0xDEADBEEF .. well that's an address now. It may or may not be a valid address (hopefully valid, an invalid stack is kind of a bad thing), but that's an other matter.

> Also what is the difference between the two movl functions?

The one used in the "push" writes to memory, the one used in the "pop" reads. Brackets on the right side means it's a write, on the left side it's a read. So can you switch them around? Obviously not, it would do something different. `movl (%ebp), %esp` would read something from memory and then change where the stack is.

> As a follow-up then, why can't we have the source and destination be memory references like so?

Because you can't, there is no such instruction. It wouldn't fit the normal [operand encoding](http://sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm.htm). I suppose an instruction like that could have existed, but it doesn't, so you can't use it.

> `movb (%esp, %edx, 4), %dh` if the source is more than 1 byte (the size of %dh), then what happens?

It isn't, by definition that instruction will read 1 byte.